# html table with submit button to update each individual table row using data from SQL database

Tags: java, html, sql-server, jsp, html-table

I have a html table which prints out information from an SQL database using a for loop. There is a submit button on each row of the html table. When the user clicks on this button the row updates. This command works but if there are multiple rows with the same primary key in the database only the final row updates and the values for all rows in the database with the same primary key are set to the same value as the final row in the table.

I need the button on each row in the table to only update a single row, not multiple rows with the same identifier. I am new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Below is the code I have been using:

```
<html>
<%
Connection objConn = null;
MedicationList objMedicationList=null;
Medication [] objMedication;

OutputLogs objLog=null;
int intDebug=0;
String strDebug;
String sessionUsername, sessionHCN; 
String pmedicationtype=null;
String pdose=null;
String pinstructions=null;
String pcomments=null;
int pvalid=0;

//try{
    objConn=(Connection)session.getAttribute(Patientportal.PortalConstants.SESSION_ATTR_DBCONNECTION);
    objLog=(OutputLogs)session.getAttribute(Patientportal.PortalConstants.SESSION_ATTR_DEBUG_OBJECT);
    intDebug=(int)session.getAttribute(Patientportal.PortalConstants.SESSION_ATTR_DEBUG_FLAG);

    //objPortalUserList=new PatientDetailsList(intDebug,objLog);
    objLog=new OutputLogs(intDebug);

    objMedicationList=new MedicationList(intDebug,objLog);

    sessionUsername=(String)session.getAttribute(Patientportal.PortalConstants.SESSION_ATTR_USERNAME);
    sessionHCN=(String)session.getAttribute(Patientportal.PortalConstants.SESSION_ATTR_HCN);
    if (intDebug==1){
        objLog.SendToDebug("Getting medication");
    }
    objMedication=objMedicationList.GetUserMedication(objConn, sessionHCN); 


            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Medication</th>
                    <th>Dose</th>
                    <th>Instructions</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
                    <% for(int count = 0; count < objMedication.length; count++){%>
                        <form method="post" action="MedicationPage.jsp">
                <tr>
                    <td><%out.println(objMedication[count].GetPatientMedication());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(objMedication[count].GetDose());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(objMedication[count].GetHowOften());%></td>
                    <td><%out.println(objMedication[count].GetComments());%></td> 
                    <td><input type="button" value="Request"</td>

                    <% 

                        pvalid=Integer.valueOf(objMedication[count].GetValid()); 
                        pmedicationtype=String.valueOf(objMedication[count].GetPatientMedication());
                        if(pvalid!=0){
                            pvalid=pvalid-1;  
                            objMedicationList.editPrescription(objConn, sessionHCN, pmedicationtype, pvalid); 
                    }
                 }

                %>
                </tr>    
               </form>    
            </table>
```

Comment: I left out some code I only included the code relevant to the problem

Comment: No, your html is incomplete, for example element button is not closed.

Comment: By definition, a "primary key" is a key used to **uniquely** identify a row. If you have two rows with the same primary key, you have badly designed data. It is possible to have a table with no primary key at all, but if you have no unique combination of fields, you can't expect to be able to tell two rows one from another.

Comment: I don't have a primary key in the database table but have used 'not null' to ensure the necessary columns are populated and used comparison operators in the sql command to ensure the correct data is printed in the html table

Answer (score 0):

> ...multiple rows with the same primary key in the database only the final row updates and the values for
>   all rows in the database with the same primary key are set to the same value as the final row in the
>   table...

If you really don't have a unique primary key in your db-table this will fail all the time. Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key